# Issue with query and javascript variable

Tags: javascript, ajax

I know this will require the use of AJAX but I don't know where to start with it.

```
<td class="dataTableContent" valign="top">
    <div>
        <input id="<?php echo " update_products[ " . $orders_products_id . "] [backorder_date] "; ?>" name="<?php echo " update_products[ " . 
    $orders_products_id . "][backorder_date] "; ?>" size="10" ?>onChange="backorderDate('
        <?php echo $orders_products_id; ?>')" value='
        <?php echo tep_date_short($order->products[$i]['backorder_date']); ?>'>
    </div>
</td>
```

So what I have here is an input box that requires users to input a back order date if there is one for their product. Now if you notice I have an event that activates a function onChange for this input box.

```
function backorderDate(pid)
{
<?php
    $prod_id = "<script language='JavaScript'>pid;</script>";
    echo $prod_id;

    $query_send = tep_db_query("SELECT backorder_date from pos_products WHERE 
orders_products_id= '$prod_id' ORDER BY backorder_date DESC");
    $final = tep_db_fetch_array($query_send);
?>

alert("There has been a change to the Back Order Date and this may
 change the In Stock checkbox.");
alert("<?php echo $final; ?>");
}
```

Then as you can see above this is the function that is being called. I pass the variable from the input box to the function and I named it 'pid'. Then here is where the problem begins. I need that variable's content in order to call the correct info in a query. Clearly what I have there is wrong and it most likely needs AJAX. Can anyone push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do SQL from javascript like this.  It's not only impossible, it's a huge security risk.  Assuming the PHP outputs the input correctly, change your javascript function to look something like this:

```
function backorderDate(pid)
    {
    $.ajax ({
        url: "backend.php",
        data: pid,
        success: function(data) { 
             ///do whataever you want here
        }
    })
}
```

Then create a PHP file called backend.php where you do your query, process the results, and send back data to your jQuery function.

EDIT:

Looking over this again, I'm not sure what you're trying to do here:

```
 <input id="<?php echo " update_products[ " . $orders_products_id . "] [backorder_date] "; ?>"               name="<?php echo " update_products[ " . 
$orders_products_id . "][backorder_date] "; ?>" size="10" ?>onChange="backorderDate('
    <?php echo $orders_products_id; ?>')" value='
    <?php echo tep_date_short($order->products[$i]['backorder_date']); ?>'>
```

You may mean something like this? :

```
 <input id="<?php echo $update_products[orders_products_id][backorder_date]; ?>"                          
 name="<?php echo $update_products[orders_products_id][backorder_date]; ?>" 
 size="10" 
 onChange="backorderDate('<?php echo $orders_products_id; ?>')" 
 value='<?php echo tep_date_short($order->products[$i]['backorder_date']); ?>'>
```

Without seeing more of your code, I can't really decipher where all these variables are coming from.

Comment: Sorry for the delay but how would I actually utilize the variable in backend.php without actually have type:post in the javascript code?

Am I overlooking something here?

Comment: Yes, you should have a type: 'Post' in the ajax parameters.  Sorry, my omission.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP wiz, but I'm guessing that the PHP in your JS function gets parsed and doesn't exist when the function is actually run. Therefore, the `script` tag is unnecessary.

```
function backorderDate(pid) {
    <?php echo $prod_id ?> = pid;
```